# How do I show a basic search block on the front page that integrates with search api?

Tags: blocks, search

I've been creating my search pages in Search API, but I want to offer a search block on the front page or other pages that can do what the core search block does. Is there a way to either integrate the search block, or a work around to have a search block on the front page while it pulls up search and displays everything on the main search page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Search API module has the ability to integrate with views module. All you need to do is to install views module and then create Search view,expose search filter and in your views configuration choose Exposed form in block option to yes, now you will the see the search block from your search api and place it on front page, the block will take you automatically to the search page to show the search items.

Comment: I had thought of doing that, but I wasn't certain that the exposed block would work unless it was on the same page as the view. I'll give it a shot, thanks.

Comment: I gave it a shot but it's not redirecting to my search page. I've tried creating the page as a panels page or a views page, either way the exposed for does not seem to want to redirect to search and display results. Any assistence on this would be appreciated.

Comment: what I remember is if you create a search view page and exposed your search filter as separate block, it should take you to search page. Key is the view should be same, make sure you are not confusing with two separate views one for page and one for search block.